# Megatorque motor system

Tags: terminal, system, plc, motordriver

Does anyone know how to control Megatorque motor via Handy Terminal?

The product as image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A9iw.jpg)

I got the User's Manual:http://www.nsk.com/products/megatorque/dat/C20169-03.pdf

I don't know what command sets the currents base on resistance. Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The megatorque system is an industrial servo drive system. These consist of two main parts, a servomotor which usually provides positional feedback (the feedback encoder doesn't have to mount on the motor but usually does) and a drive which has some control intelligence with a power amplifier for driving the motor. Larger systems may separate the intelligence and the amplifier.
The link you give for the user manual is only for the motor half of the system. To control the system you need to read the manual for the drive and the motor, i.e. the complete system. You can download the system user manual here: www.nsk.com/products/megatorque/dat/C20191-02.pdf.
Chapter 5 deals with operation of the system, with parameters listed in section 5.7
Your question asks for a very specific parameter which I haven't identified from the parameter lists. This is not unusual as different servodrive manufacturers use different terms for the same functions.